# Finding coefficient in a multinomial

Tags: combinatorics

Find the coefficient of $x^7$ in $(1+x+2x^3)^{10}$.

The general term is 
$$
\binom{10}{b_1,b_2,b_3} 2^{b_3} x^{b_2 + 3b_3}
$$
where $b_1,b_2,b_3\geq 0$ and $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 10$.

We want: $b_2 + 3b_3 = 7$.
So by inspection, $(b_2,b_3) = (1,2)$ or $(7,0)$.
So the coefficient of $x^7$ is equal to
$$
\binom{10}{7,1,2}2^2 + \binom{10}{3,7,0}2^0 = 1560.
$$
However, my solution says that it is $4080$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Actually I feel silly. I forgot another possible combination for $b_2,b_3$ which is $(4,1)$.  
In general for these questions, am I supposed to list out all possible values? Like, is there a pleasant way for in the case that there were more $b_\star $'s?

Comment: You mean by hand ? There is a general method to solve linear diophantine equations, but it is not easy to get all non-negative integer solutions. I think you will have to let run one variable and look for the solutions for the remaining equation. Begin with the variable with the largest coefficient.